# Angular ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to include a template sidebar and its not working. It just show a blank spot where the include should be. I have had trouble with includes every single time I try to use them. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="smartyet">
```

Include:

```
<div ng-include="'/assets/includes/controls.html'" ng-app="smartyet"></div>
```

App:

```
 var smartyet = angular.module('smartyet', ['ngAnimate']).config([function () {
  }])


smartyet.controller('ControlsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
(function($) {
  $(".containt").mCustomScrollbar({
    autoHideScrollbar: true,
    theme: "dark-3"
  });
  $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "dark-3"
  });
})(jQuery);
});
}]);


smartyet.controller('TemplateCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
(function($) {
  $("#lightGallery").lightGallery();
})(jQuery);
});
}]);

angular.module('smartyet').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.finpage1='show';$scope.finpage2='';$scope.finpage3='';$scope.finchange='';
  $scope.goodbyetext='hide'
  $scope.active_page = 'finpage2';

  $scope.togglePage1And2 = function(){
    if($scope.active_page == 'finpage1'){
      $scope.page2();
    }else{
      $scope.page1();
    }
  }
  $scope.page1 = function(){
    $scope.active_page = 'finpage1';
    $scope.finchange='show';
    $scope.finpage1='';
    $scope.finpage2='';
    $scope.finpage3='';
    $scope.hellotext='hide';
    $scope.goodbyetext='show'
  }

  $scope.page2 = function(){
    $scope.active_page = 'finpage2';
    $scope.finpage1='show';
    $scope.finpage2='';
    $scope.finpage3='';
    $scope.finchange='';
    $scope.hellotext='show';
    $scope.goodbyetext='hide';
  }

  $scope.page3 = function(){
    $scope.active_page = 'finpage3';
    $scope.finpage2='show';
    $scope.finpage1='';
    $scope.finpage3='';
    $scope.finchange='';
    $scope.hellotext='show';
    $scope.goodbyetext='hide';
  }

  $scope.page4 = function(){
    $scope.active_page = 'finpage4';
    $scope.finpage3='show';
    $scope.finpage1='';
    $scope.finpage2='';
    $scope.finchange='';
    $scope.hellotext='show';
    $scope.goodbyetext='hide';
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the app before the `ng-include`. Only load `ng-app` once.

```
<html ng-app="smartyet">
  <div ng-include="'assets/includes/controls.html'"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: I got it to work, but only when I added ng-app="" to the body or html tag. Why does the ng-app need to be empty? I'm really trying to understand how the includes work.

Comment: Are you trying to ng-include the ng-app ?

Comment: `ng-app` sets up Angular, includes won't work until that happens.

Comment: No, I'm tyring to ng-include the html file. Its a partial html file that is the left sidebar to my website.

Comment: So basically the `ng-app="smartyet"` grabs  `angular.module('smartyet', [])` and lets all `ng-*` directives & `{{}}`'s to work on the page.

Comment: if I put ng-app="smartyet" on the html tag. The includes don't work. Any idea how I can get the includes to work? Because I need the other functions in the app to work on that page. I also need the includes to work. It seems like I cant get both includes and functions to work at the same time. I changed my code to exactly what you said, and the includes don't work.

Comment: Here's a plunker showing what you're trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/SFUe8zYqMxDnjrLiOwxW?p=preview

Comment: The problem may be your path to `assets/includes/controls.html`. Drop the prefixing '/' & make sure the path is relative to your `index.html`.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. If I have <body ng-app=""> it works fine. The minute I add smartyet in between the quotes, it is a blank white page :(

Comment: Check if any app is running by adding `{{ 1 + 1 }}` to your index.html. If it's not working, then you probably need a `<script src="app.js"></script>` tag to load your app file.

Comment: Can you look at this? http://plnkr.co/edit/aqzJeRhoENhaXU4XsVSc?p=preview  Add smartyet between the quotes to see how it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81921/discussion-between-shmck-and-kimberlyvoo).